# Is it possible to send post request to single API twice or more at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a scenario that when data failed to insert to database or no connection, I collect those failed GPS coordinates data and saved to my persistent storage on phone. Once connection available I have to insert those failed data on the same API that I'm using normally when connection is ok. Is this possible or do I need to create different route api? I asked this because our QA told sometimes it work sometimes not.

```
  const location_datas = store.getState().userReducer.location_data; //failed datas not being inserted
        if(location_datas.length > 0){
          
          //insert the 

          await profileService.updateDriverLocations({ //bulk insert of failed data tried to send
            data: location_datas,
          }).then(async res =>{
            const data = res.data;
            const status = res.status;
            store.dispatch(clearLocationData());
          
          })
          .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
          });


        }
          //GPS Coordinates data
          await profileService
          .updateDriverLocations({ //same API of bulk insert above.
            data: [locs]
          })
          .then(async res => {
            const data = res.data;
            const status = res.status;
            console.log(`Status: ${status}: pasok`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            const msg = err.response.data.error.message;
            console.log(msg);
       
            store.dispatch(setLocationData(locs));
            
          });
```

Comment: Yes, you can use same api.

Comment: I can't see a reason that it should work, but in my opinion, this case should have a dedicated API endpoint, meaning you could send all these unsaved data in one request, and process them accordingly. of course it requires modifying the API.